# Why does String.match return duplicate item in result array?

Tags: javascript, regex

Why does

```
"abc123".match(/(\d{3})/)
```

return

```
[ "123", "123" ]
```

instead of just

```
["123"]
```

Isn't the expression equivalent to find exactly three digits?

Comment: The first element of the matched array is the whole matched string, the rest are capture groups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It returns two results because you've used a capturing group.

In the results array, `results[0]` will contain what was matched by the complete expression, `results[1]` will contain what was matched by the first capturing group, and so on.

In your case, both the complete expression and the first group yield the same result.